# Calculating gains for Op-amps with real AC voltages

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain

I'm a uni student trying to figure out how to calculate gains of op-amps with recorded real AC voltage inputs and outputs. We are expected to somehow know this for some post-lab work without being told how to do it in any of the lectures.

I'm assuming the gain is still defined as \$ v_{\mathbb{out}}/v_{\mathbb{in}} \$, which would mean the gain would vary of time. I know what the period, peak-to-peak voltages, and crest and trough input and output voltages are. Where do I go from here?

EDIT: By "real AC voltage" I mean actual AC voltages produced and recorded in a laboratory with real circuits; not hypothetical AC voltages with ideal circuits.

Comment: Measuring an opamp's open loop gain isn't trivial at all. You should do some research into the subject by reading for example: http://sales.moritani.co.jp/dp/omicron/notes-details/op-amp-open-loop-gain.pdf  or https://waset.org/publications/10006326/a-test-methodology-to-measure-the-open-loop-voltage-gain-of-an-operational-amplifier try to understand why they do the measurements like that. Think about what the consequence is of a 10 uV DC offset at the opamp's input when it has a DC gain of 1 million.

Comment: Also when dealing with opamps. "Opamps for Everyone" is a **must read** http://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie:I am doubting that a, what seems as 'new', student has been given the assignment to measure the open loop gain..

Comment: @HarrisonO: Well the gain doesn't vary, why do you think that? Anyway, what is the definition of gain? As you wrote, it is vout/vin, but does it matter if it RMS, peak-to-peak or what? And why does it/doesnt it?

Comment: @Linkyyy I share your doubts but when I re-read the question I cannot reach a different conclusion than that the students are expected to determine the gain of an opamp. And an opamp's **open loop** gain **does** vary, over temperature, per sample and almost anything else. That's why we generally use opamps with a **feedback circuit** to determine the gain using resistor ratios.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: Sure. I will delete my comment if he clarrifies that it is indeed open loop he is measuring

Comment: I see nothing indicating that the question is about open loop gain.

Comment: In a real situation it's better to define gain as \$\Delta Vout/\Delta Vin\$ as there will always be some offset voltage. Open loop gain also begins to drop at a very low frequency (maybe 10Hz) so if your circuit is high closed loop gain it may have an effect on the closed-loop gain at a relatively low frequency. Better to define your actual situation a bit better and maybe we can give some useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HarrisonO - I suppose, I know what you really mean. (By the way, what in your opinion is a "real" AC voltage?).

**My answer**: No - the gain is not varying with time.
For AC signals it makes no sense to find the ratio Vout/Vin for **momentary** values of both signals. Instead, the gain is defined for mean values of the sinusoidal signals - more  correct: For "root mean square rms" (magnitude ratio).

This applies to all amplifiers - single BJT stages or opamps, which in all cases are operated with signal negative feedback (and not open-loop).
Because all amplfiers contain reactive elements, it is - in addition - common practice not only to calculate (or simulate) the magnitude ratio but also to find the phase shift between input and output.

The existence of a frequency-dependent phase shift is another argument against the usage of momentary values for finding the gain.

Comment: Real AC voltage as in an experimental AC voltage with real circuits performed in a laboratory, not hypothetical voltages with ideal voltages.

Comment: Would the gain of AC voltages be the same if calculated using the peak-to-peak values if the input and output voltages are centered around the x-axis (or time axis)? I.e. if the means of \$ v_{\mathbb{in}} \$ and \$ v_{\mathbb{out}} \$ equal 0, then does \$ v_{\mathbb{out,RMS}} / v_{\mathbb{in,RMS}}  = v_{\mathbb{out,mean}} / v_{\mathbb{in,mean}} \$?

Comment: @HarrisonO, of course - the result would be the same, provided the signal is sinusoidal...